# Android - CameraDevice was already closed

Tags: android, android-camera2, device-orientation

I was trying so long for Camera2 api integration to my app. When i switch from portrait mode to landscape it throws exception

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: CameraDevice was already closed
at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.checkIfCameraClosedOrInError(CameraDeviceImpl.java:1984)
at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.submitCaptureRequest(CameraDeviceImpl.java:825)
at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.setRepeatingRequest(CameraDeviceImpl.java:880)
at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraCaptureSessionImpl.setRepeatingRequest(CameraCaptureSessionImpl.java:231)
at com.essentialsln.memtalk.ui.fragments.Camera2Fragment$11.onConfigured(Camera2Fragment.java:795)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at android.hardware.camera2.dispatch.InvokeDispatcher.dispatch(InvokeDispatcher.java:39)
at android.hardware.camera2.dispatch.HandlerDispatcher$1.run(HandlerDispatcher.java:65)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Comment: Did you find a fix for this ?

Answer (score 3):

I faced a similar problem and this helped me. If you have been referring to the [Sample app](https://github.com/googlearchive/android-Camera2Video), you should stop the thread in your CameraDevice.StateCallback by overriding the onClosed(CameraDevice) method:

```
 mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(outputSurfaces,
                new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClosed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                        super.onClosed(session);
                        stopBackgroundThread();
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case this error was preceded by

```
2020-12-15 18:31:55.703 5079-5079/com.android.example.camera2.video W/CameraDevice-JV-0: Stream configuration failed due to: createStream:1008: Camera 0: Surface already has a stream created for it (ID 0)
2020-12-15 18:31:55.704 5079-5079/com.android.example.camera2.video E/CameraCaptureSession: Session 0: Failed to create capture session; configuration failed
```

The problem was that I was adding surfaces to a list and adding it as a target but not clearing it.
I was also `setRepeatingRequest` in `updateRepeatingRequest` before `override fun onConfigured(s: CameraCaptureSession) {`

Clearing surfaces in `initializeCamera()` and removing the additional updateRepeatingRequest fixed it for me.

Comment: Sounds like the correct answer - but I did not understand - can you explain better or give code examples? you can setup all possible surfaces at start, no? and add the surfaces to each setRepeatingRequest before starting it. need to clear the surfaces before changing? never saw that in any practice but it makes sense.

Comment: It's a long time back but I think if you do `setRepeatingRequest` before `onConfigured` you will get this error (I have not confirmed again). You can check my working app on how to handle the code `https://source.codeaurora.org/quic/la/camera-samples`

Comment: About the clearing surfaces part. I am now doing it in `clearStreams()` inside `onClosed` of the `CameraBase.kt` in `https://source.codeaurora.org/quic/la/camera-samples`. I now believe that it is a different error. (You can check the error by removing it)

Comment: Thanks a lot - I will check it.